# Only do event after complete

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, telerik

How to do the event handling when the user presses the ENTER key or leaves the focus on the particular textbox? I tried for `KeyChanged` event, but it will keep updating the number instead of only once when complete.

```
private void txtNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtNumber.Text = double.Parse(txtNumber.Text).ToString("F2");
}
```

Comment: You are updating the text causes textchanged event to fire again. You can handle the Lostfocus event handler

Comment: Is this WinForms?  If so perhaps override the `Validating` event?

Comment: @VimalCK I will try this if it worked, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @MickyD Yes, it's WinForms with Telerik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the posted code. One issue is that doing the formatting each time the user “types” a character is going to be awkward for the user. In addition, if the user presses the “Enter” key, the event `txtNumber_TextChanged` is not going to fire. I assume you may already know this.

Next, when getting input from users, it is imperative that you check the input for valid numbers BEFORE calling the parse method…Example, the line of code…

```
double.Parse(txtNumber.Text).ToString("F2");
```

Will FAIL and crash the program if the text in the text box… `txtNumber.Text` is NOT a valid double.

You should always assume the user is going to make a mistake and you don’t want your code to crash when they do.

Therefore I suggest using the `double.TryPasre` method to avoid these possible crashes, calling this method will NEVER throw an exception and will make validating the number easier.

To get what you want I recommend you wire up three (3) events for the text box…

The `Leave` event, this is used to format the text, when the user leaves the text box, like when they click on another control.

Next is the `PreviewKeyDown` event, this is used when the user presses the “Enter” key.

And one extra event to help the user ONLY add numbers and one dot. The `KeyPressed` event is wired up and will ignore any pressed keys that are not numbers or the dot (period). Also, it will only allow one period, if the user tries to add a second decimal place, it will be ignored.

Bear in mind, the key pressed event helps by preventing the user from “typing” alpha text into the text box… however, the user can still paste text. Fortunately, since we are using the `TryParse` method, when the pasted text is an invalid number, the try parse will simply return “0.00” and NOT crash the code.

```
private void txtNumber_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  double.TryParse(txtNumber.Text.Trim(), out double number);
  txtNumber.Text = number.ToString("F2");
}

private void txtNumber_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
    double.TryParse(txtNumber.Text.Trim(), out double number);
    txtNumber.Text = number.ToString("F2");
  }
}

private void txtNumber_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) // <- key pressed is not a control key
    && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)  // <- key pressed is not a digit (number)
    && e.KeyChar != '.') {       // <- key pressed is not a dot (.)
    e.Handled = true;            // <- if its not a control key, digit or dot... then ignore it
  }
  // only allow one decimal point - if there is already a dot, then ignore the second one
  if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtNumber.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1) {
    e.Handled = true;            // <- if there is already a dot in the text... then ignore it
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatting a text value in a `TextBox` must be done once the input is already done.

`TextChanged`, occurs when the Text property value changes. So this is not ideal.

The only event you can rely on.

- `LostFocus`, occurs when the control loses focus. [You can sheck some info when control change focus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).

> ```
> private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
> {
>    // Code here
> }
> ```

Sometimes we wanted the format to be changed once we click something on the keyboard, so here are the possible events for that.
[The non-character keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

- `KeyDown`, occurs when a key is pressed while the control has focus.
- `KeyUp`, occurs when a key is released while the control has focus.
- `KeyPress`, occurs when a character. space or backspace key is pressed while the control has focus.
  Note: When using the `KeyPress` you need to also consider if the Form is the one handling the input events first or not, check the [Remarks here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

> ```
> private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
> {
>   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return) // You can also use: e.KeyValue == 13
>   {
>       // Do your code here
>   }
> };
> ```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Comment: @MickyD, thank you for this advise. And giving this link.